# how to close all notifications when app is closed flutter?

Tags: flutter

Does anyone have idea? Whenever I close my app, the notification also will automatically close. I try to using "AppLifecycleState.detached" but still doesn't work. It's didn't call out the function of "notifications.cancelAll()". Does anyone got idea to fix this other than using AppLifecycleState? Below are my code:

```
@override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    print("State: "+state.toString());
   if(state == AppLifecycleState.detached){
      print("detached");
      notifications.cancelAll();
    }
  }
```